# What's the best way to implement a search bar in the mobile view of a responsive site?

Tags: gui-design, search, responsive-design, filter

I'm currently working on a site that is content heavy and want to add FAYT (find-as-you-type) search.

In the desktop view I have a regular search field in the top right hand corner with a magnifying glass button on the right.

In the mobile view, the magnifying glass becomes an icon to the right of the header.  I'm thinking about making the search field expand when the magnifying glass is clicked but it will cover the logo.

Another solution is to have the search slide out as a panel from the right.  This will mirror how the navigation menu works on the left (hamburger icon).  It will also allow more room for the filtered search results.

Which solution is best? Or is there another better solution?

Comment: Why does the logo being covered bother you? If they click the search icon, then the thing they want to do is search, so that's the most important thing to the user. I think you had a good idea with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I have worked on one website. IT is given on right top corner and when clicked it slides down.both the pictures are added[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah welcome 